# Ayuda para acceder a un atributo de otro método de la misma clase

Tags: python, tkinter, class

Intentaré ser lo más resumido posible:

Necesito usar la instrucción:

```
Button(miFrame, text= P1, width=20, height=26, relief=GROOVE, fg="grey85",bg="grey94", command = lambda:Interfaz.AccionBoton("1")).place(x=10,y=70)
```

Pero el atributo `miFrame` es de otro método. ¿Como puedo hacer referencia a ese atributo desde otro método de la misma clase para ubicar un botón en ese **`frame`**?

Dejo el código.

```
#librerias
from tkinter import *
import os
import time #time.sleep(3) así se invocan 3 segundos de pausa

Ruta_Raiz = os.path.dirname(__file__)                                                                                   #Determina la ruta de esta APP

#clase principal
class Interfaz:
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        print ("Se inicio interfaz ", nombre)

    def Crea_Marco(self, XPOS_VENTANA, YPOS_VENTANA, TEXTO_TITULO_VENTANA, BOTON_EXIT):
        self.XPOS_VENTANA = XPOS_VENTANA
        self.YPOS_VENTANA = YPOS_VENTANA
        self.TEXTO_TITULO_VENTANA = TEXTO_TITULO_VENTANA
        self.BOTON_EXIT = BOTON_EXIT

        AnchoFrame = 800                                                                                                #parametro de ancho del frame
        AltoFrame  = 500                                                                                                #parametro de alto del frame
        Centro_Frame = ((AnchoFrame/2) - (len(TEXTO_TITULO_VENTANA)*5))                                                 #Calculo de centro del titulo

        root= Tk()
        root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (XPOS_VENTANA,YPOS_VENTANA))                                                           #root.geometry("+%d+%d" % (240,20)) #Posicion de la ventana
        root.overrideredirect(1)                                                                                        #sin bordes
        root.title("Ventana")                                                                                           #titulo
        root.resizable(False,False)                                                                                     #no puede cambiar de tamaño
        root.config(bd=15)                                                                                              #grosot borde
        root.config(relief="groove", bg="black")                                                                        #stilo borde

        miFrame=Frame(root, width=AnchoFrame, height=AltoFrame)                                                                     #tamaño del frame
        miFrame.config(relief="groove", bg="grey94")                                                                    #stilo de frame
        miFrame.pack()                                                                                                  #empaquetado del frame

        miLabel=Label(miFrame, text=TEXTO_TITULO_VENTANA, font=("Helvetica",16),fg="grey",bg="grey94")                  #titulo ventana
        miLabel.place(x=Centro_Frame, y=20) #miLabel.place(x=240,y=20)

        if BOTON_EXIT == 1:
            boton = Button(miFrame, text="  X  " , command= lambda:quit() , relief=GROOVE, fg="grey85",bg="grey94").place(x=760,y=10) #boton de salir

    def Crea_Menu(self, P1, P2, P3, P4):
        self.P1 = P1
        Button(miFrame, text= P1, width=20, height=26, relief=GROOVE, fg="grey85",bg="grey94", command = lambda:Interfaz.AccionBoton("1")).place(x=10,y=70)

    def AccionBoton(numero):
        print ("Se presionó el boton ", numero)

    def Inicia_Ventana(self):
        mainloop()

if __name__=="__main__":
    XPOS_VENTANA   =  240                                    #Posicion en Y de la ventana
    YPOS_VENTANA   =  20                                     #Posición en X de la ventana
    TITULO_VENTANA =  "Este es el título de la ventana"      #título de la ventana
    BOTON_EXIT     =  1                                      #tienes boton de finalizar app? 1=si 0=no

    VENTANA_1 = Interfaz    ("Ventana1")                                                
    Interfaz.Crea_Marco     (VENTANA_1, XPOS_VENTANA, YPOS_VENTANA, "ESTA ES LA VENTANA 1", BOTON_EXIT)
    Interfaz.Crea_Menu      (VENTANA_1, "Item 1","Item 2","Item 3","Item 4")

    Interfaz.Inicia_Ventana (VENTANA_1)
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: tho70 tienes una estructura de clase bastante forzada en mi opinión y que hace el código más complicado de lo que debería ser, ¿Por qué no usas el `__init__` para crear los widgets e inicializar la clase?, este es el método que debe inicializar los atributos de instancia, no deberías hacer esto desde otros métodos. Por cierto aplicar el método `mainloop` sobre una instancia de `Interfaz` no es posible, la llamada a `Inicia_Ventana` es incorrecta en si misma también... Te recomiendo mirarte las guías de estilo definidas en [PEP - 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: FJSevilla gracias por tu pronta respuesta. 
La idea es tener una clase donde se fabriquen las diversas interfaces que necesitaré llamando a los métodos adecuados; frame, botones, label etc. Reutilizando la misma clase. Echaré un ojo a lo que me sugieres.

Answer (score 1):

Las variables de una función (o método) son locales a esa función (o método) y por tanto no son accesibles desde fuera.

Pero ya que ambos métodos pertenecen a un mismo objeto, puedes guardar esa información en un atributo del objeto, en lugar de una variable local del método. Basta que pongas `self.miFrame` en lugar de `miFrame` (en ambos métodos que la usen).

Comment: Gracias abulafia: intentaré lo que me dices.